# Modern shader based Open GL : Hierarchical modeling of 3D objects

Tags: opengl, graphics

I'm trying to model a human body using cubes, spheres and such.

But I don't know how to actually model a hierarchical geometry in OpenGL 3.3+ . 
For example, if the shoulder is rotated, it should also move the arm (and not just leave the arm where it was). In some sense, how do I "connect" or "link" objects like that? That is, the arm should be connected to the shoulder at the elbow, and the torso should connect with the legs at the hips..etc

Are there good resources that explain this with code?

Answer (score 1):

it's quite simple actually:

You create a object matrix that to apply transformations to and a stack to store copies

```
mat4 objectMatrix;
stack<mat4> stack;
```

then you can emulate the old fixed function pipeline:

```
stack.push(objectMatrix);
objectMatrix.translate(shoulderOffset);
objectMatrix.rotate(shoulderRotation);
glUniformMatrix4fv(OBJECTMAT, 1, GL_FALSE, objectMatrix.data());
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, shoulderStartIndex, shoulderNumVertices);

{
    stack.push(objectMatrix);
    objectMatrix.translate(armOffset);
    objectMatrix.rotate(armRotation);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(OBJECTMAT, 1, GL_FALSE, objectMatrix.data());
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, armStartIndex, armNumVertices);

    //and so on

    objectMatrix = stack.pop();
}

objectMatrix =  stack.pop();
```

You can also push all used matrices (for all "bones") like constructed above in the shader and add a list of weights to each vertex so you can do the following in the shader

```
mat4 objMat =  mat4(0,0,0,0,
                    0,0,0,0,
                    0,0,0,0,
                    0,0,0,0);
for(int i = 0; i< 10){
    obj+=matrices[i]*weights[i];
}
```

This will be lighter on the number of uniform changes and draw calls and allows blending of matrices

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to implement a bone (skeletal) animation. I think it is rather complex subject for someone new to 3d graphics.

The implementation differs depending wheather you use fixed or shader based pipeline; VBOs or immediate mode.

Quick search on Google returned this:

- http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Basic_Bones_System
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeletal_animation

Answer (score 1):

firstly, this issue isn't really graphics related as such, its more logic related.

So to start off with, we will model our object structure as a tree, with our torso for example, being the root of our tree. Each node on the tree will contain a model, and a matrix that represents that model and some information on how this node relates to its parent node. For example its origin is 5 units in positive X, and 1 unit in negative Y and 0 units in Z away from the origin of the parent.

Now with this information we can do a lot, when we draw our model, we will keep an overall translation, and rotation matrix. We draw our root first, and apply its matrices to its vertices. Then we draw each of its children, and we propagate the changes made in the root node, to all of its children. This means everytime our root node moves, all of its children will move with it, and its childrens children, etc. We can also apply rotations to each node, in fact you can store any other information in each of these nodes, its all dependant on your design.

This is just a very basic idea of how you can achieve what you are looking for, there are also other techniques that you can use to model this behaviour, some are bone based and allow a lot more freedom of animation but are a lot more complex. I recommend first getting this down, and then moving onto the more complex stuff. As for drawing your vertices, You can have a mesh object in each node which has a VBO and a simple draw method, this is really trivial though, its literally just loading in some vertice information and then that's it. Your translation matrix and rotation matrix will do the rest.

Hope this helps!